# Wired connection from CLI with NetworkManager - "up" in elegant way

Tags: command-line, networkmanager

Sometimes I need to do some operational work in text mode
and I need to setup internet connection from command line (without any networkmanager applet).

(Please note: that when I run Window Manager, I have network connection immediately, thanks to NetworkManager applet.)

When I list my connections and look for wired one:

```
# nmcli con | grep Wired
New Wired Connection      b15ffacf-a5c58-44af-b755-b30c6d52e53e   802-3-ethernet    Thu Dec 27 21:31:21 2012
```

I get `uuid` and with it it's easy:

```
nmcli con up uuid b15ffacf-a5c58-44af-b755-b30c6d52e53e eth0
```

If someone wants to automate stuff, it goes like this:

```
nmcli con up uuid "$( nmcli con | awk '/Wired/ {print $4}' )" eth0
```

It's correct and working solution, but I have a feeling that there must be more elegant way to "up" this "Wired" device.

Could you suggest more elegant way ?

Comment: You don't need `grep` with `awk`: `awk '/Wired/ {print $4}'` will suffice...

Comment: Ok, I improved command according to your suggestion, but still it's not final solution, I am looking for.

Comment: `nm-online` should connect you to the available network(s).

Comment: surprisingly `nm-online` does not connect me to wired connection... only to wifi, when it's available.